# How to keep Chrome bookmarks up to date?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I have recently synced all my bookmarks from my Chrome in my personal laptop to Chrome at work. Now every time I add new bookmarks or edits them at work I want to be able to see them on my laptop at home. I can't seem to find it on Advanced Sync Settings on Chrome's Settings. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can go for a free application, Xmarks. By paying a fee, it is available on mobile devices as well, while the free version works on any browser and any operating system.

Comment: I tried this eysterday and it's doing what I need. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

There is an option in Advanced Sync Settings. It's called Bookmarks in the last row.

If you want, just choose Sync Everything, and it will be synced.

You have 2 Ways to force the sync:

1. Disable Sync and then Sync again.
2. Add a bookmark and delete it - it will force the Sync

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well and it doesn't seem to sync the current version of my bookmarks at home.

Comment: You have 2 Ways to force the sync:

1)Disable Sync and than Sync again.

2)Add a bookmark and delete it-It will force the Sync

Comment: If there is no back and forth syncing without losing any bookmarks or duplicates, I guess this will be the solution. Since I make changes in both places and I was just curious if there was a way to keep both sides up to date. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Following up to what @BestAmy said, this should happen automatically if you are logged into Chrome with your google account on both machines.

If that's the case and the sync isn't happening you could perform some trouble shooting.

Type this into chrome:

```
chrome://sync/
```

If you see that bookmark synching is disabled then, in *Advanced Sync settings*,
you can switch *synch everything* to *choose what to sync* and then uncheck *bookmarks* , save , and then re-check *bookmarks*.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Arch / Debian, or are running a development / testing version of Chrome by now you should know that you can manually delete everything that has ever synced from Google's server over at https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync. One can then force sync Google bookmarks again. This will take hours though.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the wrong place maybe i found that they were not under bookmarks but under Starred Items in Chrome on mobile. I thought they were not synced but they were in a diffrent local.

Comment: The OP mentioned Chrome on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome did a great update who fix this issue!

You just have to use chrome://settings/syncSetup from your browser with a mail address and that's it.

It will sync on all device you just have to connect to your mail address on every device.